# Access XML from 3rd-party SOAP service?

Tags: soap, jersey, jax-rs

I'm using a vendor-created SOAP client to access their SOAP service in my Jersey 1.3 REST application.

In certain cases, I would like like to access the response's XML, instead of the client's proxy class.  Is there a way to do this?

I also have access to their WSDL if that would make this easier to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JAX-WS Dispatch client to put your hands on XML:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPBody;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage;
import javax.xml.ws.Dispatch;
import javax.xml.ws.Service;
import javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPBinding;

import org.w3c.dom.Node;

public class DispatchClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String wsdlAddress = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/news/NewsWS?wsdl";
        URL wsdl = new URL(wsdlAddress);

        QName serviceName = new QName("http://news/", "NewsWebService");
        QName portName = new QName("http://news/", "NewsPort");

        //nie ma WSDL-a
        Service service = Service.create(serviceName);
        service.addPort(portName, SOAPBinding.SOAP12HTTP_BINDING, "http://127.0.0.1:8080/news/NewsWS");     


        Dispatch<SOAPMessage> dispatch = service.createDispatch(portName,
                SOAPMessage.class, Service.Mode.MESSAGE);

        MessageFactory mf = MessageFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPMessage req = mf.createMessage(null, new FileInputStream("NewsCountSoapRequest.xml"));

        SOAPMessage res = dispatch.invoke(req);

        SOAPBody body = res.getSOAPBody(); //SOAP body XML
    }
}
```

You can work with SOAP body XML using DOM interface (all these Node madness) or use XPath.